# Why do I get "Unable to start service Intent"?

Tags: java, android, service, android-intent

I'm trying get some licensing code from AndroidPit.com working, but I get "Unable to start service Intent". Basically my code looks like this:

```
        Intent licenseIntent = new Intent("de.androidpit.app.services.ILicenseService");            
        if (mContext.bindService(licenseIntent, this, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE))
        {
            // success
        }
        else
        {
            // failure (I get this all the time(
        }
```

I tried passing ILicenseService class explicitly:

```
        Intent licenseIntent = new Intent(mContext, de.androidpit.app.services.ILicenseService.class);
```

but I still get the same problem.

I managed to get Android Market LVL library working which uses identical code, so I don't really understand why it fails to find "de.androidpit.app.services.ILicenseService", but manages to find "com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService".

Most of the answers I found here say that you need to append stuff to your AndroidManifest.xml, but you don't anything for "com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService" to work, so I guess I shouldn't need anything "de.androidpit.app.services.ILicenseService" (they both derive from android.os.IInterface).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you remembered to add the service to your manifest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution in my case was to start a server part on my phone (AppCenter from AndroidPit.com in this case). No entries in AndroidManifest are necessary for the client application.

Answer (score 1):

> Most of the answers I found here say that you need to append stuff to your AndroidManifest.xml

Those answers are correct.

> but you don't anything for "com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService" to work

That is because `com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService` is a remote service, one that is not in your project, but rather in the firmware of the device.

> so I guess I shouldn't need anything "de.androidpit.app.services.ILicenseService" (they both derive from android.os.IInterface).

That is flawed reasoning. By your argument, `java.util.HashMap` does not go in the manifest, and both `java.util.HashMap` and any implementation of `Activity` all derive from `Object`, so therefore you do not need to put your activities in the manifest. If you try this, you will quickly discover that your activities no longer work.

If it is a component (activity, service, content provider, or some implementations of `BroadcastReceiver`), and the implementation of the component is in your project (directly, via a JAR, via a library project, etc.), you must have an entry in the manifest for it.

Wherever you got the service from should provide you with instructions for adding the service to your manifest, and they should also supply you with instructions for creating the `Intent` used to bind to it. If they do not provide this documentation, perhaps you should reconsider your use of this product.

Comment: Thanks - the insight that service is remote was very helpful (I'm new to whole this Intent logic). I can see that Client applications do not need entries in AndroidManifest.xml (for example: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/AdvServices/RemoteClient). Is there a good article how Android finds these remote services and where/how does it look for them?

Comment: @Paulius Liekis: "Is there a good article how Android finds these remote services and where/how does it look for them?" -- Android finds them by the `Intent` you use. An SDK application advertises a service for use by other applications by adding an `<intent-filter>` to it in most cases. The `com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService`, being more tied to the firmware, may not be publicized like an SDK application would, and since it's not open source (AFAIK) we can't tell.